# Как открыть один сайт несколько раз используя TWebBrowser из потоков?

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, webbrowser

Есть один контрол `TWebBrowser` и мне нужно заходить на один и тот же сайт в разных потоках. Например:

1. Открываю первый поток открываю сайт привет.ру
2. Открываю второй поток открываю сайт привет.ру
   и т.д.

Куки которые получают веббраузеры в потоках не должны пересекаться. Можно это как-то реализовать или нет?

Comment: Александр, постановка вопроса достаточно сумбурна. Вам необходимо реализовать открытие сайта из потоков или же избежать пересечения `cookies` сайтов, в то время как они открыты из потоков?

Comment: Дмитрий, верно мне нужно и одно и другое.

Comment: Я почти уверен, что компонент `TWebBrowser` должен работать в гуевом потоке. Запустить его в другом потоке, вероятно, можно, но с извращениями. Не проще ли запустить несколько процессов?

Comment: Александр, какие-нибудь наработки по Вашему вопросу у Вас имеются? Пытались ли Вы реализовать Вашу идею? Если да - добавьте необходимый для демонстрации Вашего решения код в "тело" вопроса. Если никаких наработок у Вас нет, то *писать код за Вас никто не будет*. Также не помешает прочитать это: [ask]

Comment: Запустить-то, похоже, получится, но нормальной работы достичь не удастся. Либо, как указали выше, несколько процессов, либо, например, использовать  тот же IWebBrowser2.